# Controlling excessive row margins in a view

Tags: css, view, xpages

I'm doing a view panel from one of my notes views. It doesn't look bad but I can't seem to control the top & bottom margins of each row. I'd like to crunch them together more. You can almost fit another whole line in betweed those rows. Here's a sample of the code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
         xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
<xp:this.resources>
  <xp:styleSheet href="/styles.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
<xc:ExpandCollapse viewPanelName="viewPanel1"></xc:ExpandCollapse>
<xp:viewPanel rows="60" id="viewPanel1" viewStyleClass="xspView"
              viewStyle="margin-right:px" rowClasses="even,odd">
  <xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="view1">
      <xp:this.viewName><![CDATA[Foreign\By Client & WBS]]></xp:this.viewName>
    </xp:dominoView>
  </xp:this.data>
<xp:viewColumn id="viewDocSelect" style="width:20.0px"
               showCheckbox="true" displayAs="hidden">
  <xp:this.facets>
    <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header"
                         id="viewColumnHeader4">
    </xp:viewColumnHeader>
  </xp:this.facets>
</xp:viewColumn>
<xp:viewColumn columnName="Client" id="viewColumn1"
               style="width:197.0px">
  <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Client" id="viewColumnHeader1"
                       styleClass="viewHead">
  </xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>
       .
       .
  (More column code)
       .
       .
<xp:this.facets>
  <xp:pager partialRefresh="true"
            layout="FirstImage PreviousImage 
            SeparatorPage Group NextImage LastImage"
            xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
  </xp:pager>
</xp:this.facets>
</xp:viewPanel>
</xp:view>
```

I've tried height, line-height in the styles of the viewPanel styleClass and its rowStyle class. I've tried using padding and margins in both the table and data areas. It just seems to ignore all of that. The odd,even classes I found in another article here works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what Theme if any are you using.  That's probably pretty important for this question.

Not sure if this as a great answer in itself, but have you tried going into the developer tools of your Browser and using the "Inspect Element" feature?  On the left should be all the CSS information available. 
You'll likely see additional styles applied by oneUI AFTER your custom styling.  You might need to override those styles to get what you want.

Most XPages controls also have a "disableTheme" property.  I'm not sure about the viewPanel but check that and if so try turning that off to prevent extra theme styling from loading.

Comment: Thanks. I'm so used to just using the developer tools for Javascript debugging that I didn't see that you can look at classes as well. You gave me a place to look.

Comment: Cool.  Glad that was helpful.  Would be great if you came back and filled in the details of your solution.  good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just override a few of xPage's default CSS styles in your own stylesheet.

```
/* Overrides of view row padding */
.xspColumnViewStart {padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0}
.xspColumnViewMiddle {padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0}
.xspColumnViewEnd {padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0}
```

The defaults for bottom and top are 4px. Wonder if there's a list of these out there somewhere...